# All links on website get weird border when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some problems with css on all links. When I click on a button/link i get a weird border (see picture). I dont have class with this color checked on all css files. 
http://postimg.org/gallery/sz6bc0u0/

Comment: You need to provide your HTML & CSS in a demo that shows the issue.

Comment: set outline:none to links/buttons....

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set css property outline:none on a tag.

```
a{
outline:none;
}
```

Comment: @Gienasek if this solves your problem, mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css:

```
a:hover, focus, active    {
    border: 0px !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

If you don't want the properties above to be global, just append an id or class to the anchor as well as to the above css.

Comment: It should be `a:hover, a:focus, a:active` and `background-color`, and this doesn't really solve the problem described above

Comment: @Alvaro background- added and the above comma separated markups is valid syntax too lol Nice work

Comment: The markup is valid, but it is not correct (for this case) because `a:hover, focus, active` is not the same as `a:hover, a:focus, a:active`. See it here http://jsfiddle.net/ae480mk1/ (click on the buttons, or press tab on the result window to see how they behave differently)

Answer (score 0):

I am at work and cannot access that image but I assume that it is a dotted outline, coloured the same colour as the link text.

If that is the case, the outline *should* ideally be there (or another visual equivalent) as it is important for accessibility. To demonstrate why this is important, please hide your mouse away, and on the page use the `TAB` key to select the link, then press enter to access the destination page.

Unless you provide some other type of `:focus` identifier, you will not be able to see what is currently focused.

Now try imagine that you are in someway physically unable to use a mouse and can only use the keyboard to navigate. You would be extremely frustrated by the lack of visual feedback.

Please try to keep your web application accessible -- it is really important.